# Dell P2314H Monitor Cannot Connect to Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I've got a late 2013 model 13 inch Macbook Pro with Retina Display, and a new Dell P2314H monitor. 
I keep getting a message on the monitor saying its going to sleep. I've tried the following:

1. Display port to HDMI cable where the HDMI is connected to the MBP, and the DP is connected to the monitor.
2. VGA cable to the monitor and an HDMI cable to the MBP.
3. Points 1 and 2 with Thunderbolt adapters connected.

I still keep getting the same message.

I've been using passive adapters for this, im not sure changing them to active adapters will fix this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you know how to use console, report to us for the time stamp of the event (when you connect the monitor)

Comment: Hi @Buscar웃 I don't know how to do that. Could you please tell me the command for that? I tried googling for it, but I'm afraid I couldn't find a tutorial on that.

Comment: It is simple, In Finder go to Applications >> Utility and there it is the Console.app Open it look at the system clock (time) then plug in your monitor. In the console window select events from that time for about 20-30 lines, copy and paste here.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I've added the requested logs

Answer (score 1):

Got myself an active adapter between my DVI port and hdmi. Connected one end of the DVI cable to the monitor and the other end of it to the active adapter. Data going in through the mac to the monitor was converted and it all worked like a charm.